# how can i create a property for array of labels in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, label

In my iphone app i am programmatically creating the labels ,,i am creating array of labels
 like `UILabel *lblVersionName[20];`  i need to copy the contents of the label into some string so i need to define property like

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)UILabel *lblVersionName[20];
```

but its giving error that "property can not have array of function type lblVersionName[20]"

cant we have property for array of labels(lblVersionName[20])
 please somebody do help me, thanx in advance

Comment: It is best to just keep the array as a property and then access the labels in the array as needed.

Comment: use a pointer to a pointer and allocate the memory in your init method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW6):

> **Supported Types**
>
> You can declare a property for any Objective-C class, Core Foundation data type, or “plain old data” (POD) type

So you're trying to add a property for an unsupported type.

Like Terente wrote, you should use `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`.

You might have a reason for why you need a c array, but that is only going to cause you a lot of trouble down the road. Don't fight the frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of C array just use [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) or [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: i dont want array ,,i want LabelArray like UILabel *lblVersionName[20];

Comment: Just create an NSMutableArray and populate it with your labels. Or you need to implement your setter and getters method by hand.